# DNS rerouting SSL issue

Tags: ssl, iis, dns

I have a blocklist for my internal network that reroutes the user to another IP address should there be a match. This is managed via SimpleDNS and a tool within that program. The rerouting works and it goes to the IP address.

Code on the IP website then logs the hit and reroutes to a fully qualified domain and shows the user a message.

Except I now have an issue inbetween SimpleDNS rerouting to the IP and the friendly page being showen

Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from www.starbucks.co.uk (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Automatically send some system information and page content to Google to help detect dangerous apps and sites. Privacy policy

(starbucks.co.uk is just a test site in the blocklist)

I can then click on the Advanced > Proceed and it goes to the correct location but is there anyway I can bypass that. I'm guessing it's an ssl issue somewhere somehow.

Setup is Windows Server 2016 running IIS. I have an SSL on the end domain which is installed and works correctly.

Thanks

Paul

Comment: That's the intended behavior of SSL/TLS. No third party, such as a network administrator, ISP, etc, can intercept or tamper with the connection without a bright warning being shown.

Comment: yes true but then how can I reroute things correctly?

Comment: You don't. You need to realize that SSL/TLS has been *expressly* designed to prevent you and others from tampering with it in any way.

Comment: The only way to create test certificates with the necessary common names and deploy them inside your internal network (like the man in the middle attack). As it is an internal network, you probably have the rights to fake such sites, but never can you do the same in the internet.

Comment: Nevermind IP addresses and re-routing, however you arrange the plumbing is your business, the domain name match rule is very simple: whatever hostname is in the URL that the browser is retrieving must be matched in the certificate that is eventually returned in the SSL handshake